# If/else function on a data frame to create conditional matrix

Tags: r, if-statement

Here is the data set for reproducibility:

```
    a=c(90.41,37.37,18.98)
    b=c(103.39,39.44,51.68)
    c=c(83.51,36.41,47.46)
    d=c(94.60,38.57,50.22)
    e=c(95.04,38.81,50.49)
    xx=t(data.frame(a,b,c,d,e))
    df=data.frame(xx)
```

And here is the if/else function I am trying run on the data frame

```
 classify=function(df){
 if (df>=110) {
 class="5"}
 else if (df<110 & df>=103){
 class="4"}
 else if (df<103 & df>=95){
 class="3"}
 else if (df<95 & df>=76){
 class="2"}
 else if (df<76){
 class="1"}
 else {class="none"}
 }
```

However, what I want the if/else function to produce is a new data frame that looks like this:

```
     df
     X1 X2 X3
    a  2  1  1
    b  4  1  1
    c  2  1  1
    d  2  1  1
    e  3  1  1
```

I am unsure as to how to do this so any help would be super appreciated. I anticipate something is wrong in the if/else function itself but I am quite inexperienced and I don't know how to detect errors in the script that easily. Thank you!

Comment: Read about `cut`, instead of using endless `if else`

Comment: Will do! Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
sapply(df, function(x) {as.numeric(as.character(cut(x, c(-Inf,76,95,103,110,Inf), seq(1:5))))})

     X1 X2 X3
[1,]  2  1  1
[2,]  4  1  1
[3,]  2  1  1
[4,]  2  1  1
[5,]  3  1  1
```

Use cut to set the intervals (its 2nd argument) and the labels (its 3rd argument). However, it returns a factor, so convert back to numeric if you like that. Since you want to run the function over the the full dataframe, use sapply or lapply.

Comment: You're a hero! If I had 15 reputation instead o 8 I would upvote this. Thank you so much!

Comment: Your welcome! You could consider to accept the answer if it was helpful to you. See also: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers . Edit: Obviously it does not have to be my answer, but just wanted to let you know that you can accept only one answer per question. (I noticed the accepted answer changed a few times)

Comment: That is really good answer. My opinion - it should be accepted as an answer for your question. My solution is only the illustration how you can do it using slightly modified `if`-`else` approach.

Comment: Thanks. I leave it to Luuk of course what answer to accept, I just had the feeling he did not realize only one answer can be accepted per question. I don't mind the reputation points.

Comment: Sorry guys, both your approaches worked equally well but because I needed to specify that some values where >= and <= the intervals (and there was no consistent pattern) I felt that utubun's approach worked best for me. This does not take away from Len's answer as it is also very helpful. But because of my lack of experience its easier for me to understand what I am doing using utubun's approach as it is a more step by step approach. And you guys could tell I am very new because of changing the correct answer, which I didn't know could only be one. Either way, thank you both so much!

Comment: That being said, I have highlighted Len's answer with the green tick incase other people stumble on this problem and prefer the one line of code approach.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with `findInterval`. All you have to do is to pass it a non-decreasing vector of break points.

```
classify <- function(DF, breaks = c(-Inf, 76, 95, 103, 110, Inf)){
  f <- function(x, breaks) findInterval(x, breaks)
  DF[] <- lapply(DF, f, breaks)
  DF
}

classify(df)
#  X1 X2 X3
#a  2  1  1
#b  4  1  1
#c  2  1  1
#d  2  1  1
#e  3  1  1
```

Answer (score 2):

Quite a similar approach to your example, using `case_when` from `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)

classify <- function(x){
  case_when(
    x >= 110 ~ "5",
    x >= 103 & x < 110 ~ "4",
    x >= 95 & x < 103 ~ "3",
    x >= 76 & x < 95 ~ "2",
    x < 76 ~ "1",
    TRUE ~ "none"
  )
}

a = c(90.41, 37.37, 18.98)
b = c(103.39, 39.44, 51.68)
c = c(83.51, 36.41, 47.46)
d = c(94.60, 38.57, 50.22)
e = c(95.04, 38.81, 50.49)

df <- data.frame(matrix(c(a, b, c, d, e), ncol = 3, byrow = T))

mutate_all(df, classify)

#  X1 X2 X3
#1  2  1  1
#2  4  1  1
#3  2  1  1
#4  2  1  1
#5  3  1  1
```

In case if:

```
df
#      X1    X2    X3
#1   -Inf 37.37 18.98
#2 103.39   NaN 51.68
#3  83.51 36.41 47.46
#4  94.60   Inf 50.22
#5  95.04 38.81    NA
```

The results look like this:

```
mutate_all(df, classify)
#  X1   X2   X3
#1  1    1    1
#2  4 none    1
#3  2    1    1
#4  2    5    1
#5  3    1 none
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I am very appreciative that this community is so helpful!